# How to Convert MySQL Column Value From Array to String

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, multi-select

I am working on an existing HTML form used to collect data about a project and then inserts that project record into a MySQL database using PHP.

Inside the form, there is an input field named "staff[]". This field is a multi select element, that allows users to select more than one team member to handle the project.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select multiple name="staff[]">
        <option value="1">Mary</option>
        <option value="2">Tyrone</option>
        <option value="3">Rod</option>
        <option value="4">Marcus</option>
        <option value="5">David</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

For example purposes, the user selects Tyrone, Rod and David for this particular project. If we insert the record at this point, the database only stores the first record value, which would be Tyrone's ID of 2. General practice is to store each instance in a separate table, however this is not our system and due to a restriction of 4 members for each project, management would prefer we insert a comma delimited array into each project's staff column for convenience.

In order to handle this issue, we've created a foreach loop that loops through the selected values from the dropdown menu, while ensuring a trailing comma doesn't exist:

```
// Add array into one variable
$staff_count = count($_POST['project_staff']);
$i = 0;
foreach($_POST['project_staff'] as $staff) {
    if (++$i === $staff_count) {
        $member_variable .= $staff;
    } else {
        $member_variable .= $staff . ", ";
    }
}
```

After pressing the submit button, the above script is ran (which produces an array value of (2, 3, 5)) and the record is inserted into the 'projects' table with no issues.

HEREIN LIES THE PROBLEM.

Finally we have a view page, where we will call all employees assigned to a project, based on the query parameter, which would be the project ID. For example, if the previous project ID was 6, the following URL would be used:

```
site.com/project/view/?project=6
```

From this page, I am able to save the staff list using the following variable assignment:

```
$project = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project = 6";
$employee_chosen = $project['project_employee']
```

If the 'staff' column only accepted one employee (for example, just one value of 4), the variable would have a value of one number:

```
$project['project_employee'] (4)
```

I would then be able to run a secondary query for employees as such:

```
$employee_chosen = $project['project_employee']; (4)
query2 = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_ID = $employee_chosen";
```

This would very easily bring back the one employee that was entered in the "staff" column. However, we are dealing with an array in this column value (2, 3, 5) and so I have queried the following statement:

```
$employee_list = $project['project_staff']; (2,3,5)
$query_employees = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_id IN ($employee_list)";
```

When I run this query, I receive only the first result from the employee ID 2 (as initially stated with the HTML form).

However, if I use phpMyAdmin to directly type in the three numbers as a string:

```
$query_employees = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_id IN (2,3,5)";
```

I receive all three employee records.

Just to ensure that the column ARRAY was in fact behaving as a STRING, I initiated a var_dump on the value:

```
echo var_dump($project['project_staff']);
```

After which I received the following information:

```
string(7) "4, 5, 6"
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I am satisfied with the idea that I am able to query the value, as before I received several non-object and array errors.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you may be able to provide.

Comment: Have you considered a different schema, with a many to many table that had a row for each member of staff, for each project? Then it's a simple join to find details of the staff, rather than having t query, parse, and requery

Comment: @RowlandShaw I completely agree. However, the client is a medium-sized company where I don't have much breathing room to offer better solutions.  What frustrates me most is after the var_dump, the array seems to be recognized as a string, yet the query is only bringing back the first item in the array.

Comment: Simply concatenate without parentheses: `$query_employees = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_id IN " . $employee_list;`

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, but the value of the 'project_staff' variable is a comma delimited string with three employee ID numbers (2,3,5). So I receive a query error due to those two commas inside the string not being bound by parenthesis. Thanks again.

Comment: Your above query should work as you build a string query in code just like typing a string in phpMyAdmin. Try echoing  the following and check if it is a legitimate query with IN clause, intact with parentheses and commas: `"SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_id IN (". $employee_list .")";`

Comment: I would possibly json_encode() the array and then json_decode() once you retrieve it.  As an array you can then do implode() for the IN().

Comment: I'd just mention that I think that the part you didn't ask about is not very efficient. You are getting the data as an array `$_POST['project_staff']`  if you want to store that as comma separated values use `implode(',', $_POST['project_staff'])`.  But I think you're probably even better off storing it as `json_encode($_POST['project_staff']))`.

Comment: @Elin thanks for the suggestion. I actually saw the json_encode() as an array option about an hour after trying some of Parfait's suggestions. I think I'll learn a little more about it and possibly test it out on some of my personal tables if these implode explode methods aren't working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure from what you are saying that you are storing a string `$employee_list`  that might be '2,3,4'.  Then your `IN ($employee_list)` is really `IN ('2,3,4')`  but what you really want is `IN (2,3,4)`.  There are various ways to get there but you could do

```
$employee_list = implode(','(explode(',', $employee_list));
```

Comment: Nearly my same answer in draft mode to `explode`, then `implode` but was waiting on OP to respond to my last comment. Even at the original `'2,3,4'`  string, original query, `$query_employees` should have worked.

Comment: SQL is definitely not going to know that you want to treat that as a list of integers and not a string that happens to have commas in it.  It's no different than 'a,b,c' versus 'a','b','c'.

Comment: @Elin, this worked perfectly. It appears this was an issue of an array converted to a string, which due to commas and quotes, still appeared to function as an array to the MySQL query. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Parfait thanks a lot for the guidance. It seems the help you gave me thus far was inching in this direction anyway. I would have gone a different way with this database, but we were in a situation where the environment couldn't change and we had to think of a solution that would allow for an comma delimited array of four or less IDs to sit inside of the same column value. Thanks for all of your help. Truly appreciated.